# angular.js - best practice for defining a utility library

Tags: angularjs, module, organization, modularization

I'm giving my first steps with angular, and I need to define a utility helper library, with a couple of function methods, something like

`dataHelper.parse`, `dataHelper.sanitize`, etc

What would be the recommended way to organize it in angular?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For utility methods, I would organize them in a library outside of the Angular framework, but with a small dependency on angular.extend.  If you want your library completely independent of Angular, you can substitute `extend` with  your own implementation.

Wrap your utility API in a JavaScript enclosure and expose your library as a property of `window` (in the example below, I've named my library *myLibrary*, but you're free to choose whichever name you like). By attaching your library as a property of `window`, you will be able to reference 'myLibrary' without qualification. If you are curious, this is exactly how the *angular* library is exposed.

```
 (function (window, document) {
     'use strict';

     // attach myLibrary as a property of window
     var myLibrary = window.myLibrary || (window.myLibrary = {});

     // BEGIN API
     function helloWorld() {
         alert('hello world!');
     }

     function utilityMethod1() {
         alert('Utility Method 1');
     }

     function utilityMethod2() {
         alert('Utility Method 2');
     }
     // END API

     // publish external API by extending myLibrary
     function publishExternalAPI(myLibrary) {
         angular.extend(myLibrary, {
             'helloWorld': helloWorld,
             'utilityMethod1': utilityMethod1,
             'utilityMethod2': utilityMethod2
         });
     }


     publishExternalAPI(myLibrary);

 })(window, document);
```

**Usage**

Once the script is added, you can use your library from anywhere - services, factories, providers, controllers, directives etc.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='angular.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='myLibrary.js'></script>

<script>
      myLibrary.helloWorld();
      myLibrary.utilityMethod1();
      myLibrary.utilityMethod2();
</script>
```

**Utility Library vs Angular Services**

The reason that I prefer utility functions to reside in their own library rather than in angular services is because I think of them as being separate from the angular ecosystem. These utility functions are pretty much stand-alone and are module agnostic, while angular services/factories work closely with other parts of angular, including controllers and directives, and are very much closely tied to the module.

**Extending Angular**

If you really wanted, you could even extend the angular library itself.  Just substitute `myLibrary` with `angular` in the script (Note: this may not be advisable as it would make your scripts dependent on the Angular implementation).

Comment: This is indeed a pretty good idea. Is there any way of using an Angular service in external code?

Comment: There is, but you would need to use angular's $injector: var $injector = angular.injector(); var myService = $injector.get('myService');

Comment: I am having trouble returning a value from the API functions. I've confirmed that the API function is called but from the caller, the return value is *undefined*. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom [**service**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

```
globalModule.service('toolkit',function(){

return{
   
    getDate: function(altFormat){
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = yyyy +'-'+ mm+'-'+dd;

        if(altFormat){
            today = today.replace(/-/g, '.');
        }

        return today;
    },

    /**
     *  Returns a 32 character ID [ XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ]
     * @returns {string}
     */

    newGUID: function(){

        // ...
    }

  };
});
```

You can inject it wherever it is needed. If you can bundle some logic into seperate services (e.g `parseService`) I think you should do so.

If you need something more flexible or configurable, have a look at providers.

Comment: This was downvoted. I'd be happy to hear about any suggestions the downvoter would make to improve this answer.

Comment: the one downside of this is you can't use it in a config block.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @pixelbits' answer, if you'd like to keep your external dependencies explicit, you can fairly easily wrap existing libraries for use with Angular, like this for [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):

```
angular.module('testApp')
.constant( 'moment', moment)
```