# How to remove the element with respect to array key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an javascript array as below:

```
$scope.products = [
    {id:'1', name:'IPhone6', price: '1,000 AED', quantity: '2'},
    {id:'2', name:'Samsung Mini', price: '750 AED', quantity: '1'},
    {id:'3', name:'Dell Laptop', price: '1700 AED', quantity: '3'},
    {id:'4', name:'HCL Monitor 7"', price: '650 AED', quantity: '7'},
];
```

Displaying above array using `ng-repeat` Angular js function.

I am calling a remove function and passing `id` as argument. How can I remove the particular element from the array?

`$scope.products.slice($id, 1)` is not required. I have to delete with respect to id? Please advice.

Comment: so you want to, for example remove product with an id of 3 etc from the array? you'd want splice()

Comment: Is `id` always sequential, and always greater than the index by 1? Is there any chance that different lines have the same id?

Comment: You don't want to use splice at all ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
// id = '3'

$scope.products = $scope.products.filter(function (p) { return p.id !== id });
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the splice method

1. [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
2. [W3School - splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

You might want to pass the index of the element with id you supply to the remove function, to do that you can describe a getIndexBy function

```
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][name] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
index=products.getIndexBy("id", 3)
```

where 3 is the id you supplied.
Then you can use this index in the splice method to delete the specific element.

Assuming that you are looking to take down a element by index.

Comment: Explain how to use the `splice` method with the problem described above

Comment: Please checkout how is splice used to remove items - http://jsbin.com/vesomu/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @lante : I guess that is fine right ? not worthy of a -1 at least

Comment: You are only exposing two links to MDN and W3S, but you are not explaining how to implement that methods as a solution to solve the problem described. Also you are not reading the question, because you are requiring an index, and the question says that it needs to pass an `id`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer adding more details. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could define a [utility function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604103/angular-js-best-practice-for-defining-a-utility-library/24605124#24605124):

```
(function(window) {
      var utility = window.utility|| (window.utility= {});
      function remove(items, fn) {           
           var toRemove = [];          
           angular.forEach(items, function(item, i) {  
               if (fn(item)) {
                  toRemove.push(i);
               }
            });
            angular.forEach(toRemove, function(index) {
                items.splice(index,1);
            });
      }

     angular.extend(utility, {
         'remove': remove
     });

})(window);
```

To use this function, pass an array of items as the first parameter, and a predicate function as a second parameter. All items where the predicate returns true, will remove the item from the array:

Examples:

To remove all users with the name 'john':

```
utility.remove($scope.users, function(user) {
    return user.name == 'john';
});
```

To remove a user with id 3:

```
utility.remove($scope.users, function(user) {
    return user.id == 3;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $index in click action like this

```
ng-click='slice($index);'
```

and your function like this

```
$scope.slice = function(element){
    $scope.friends.splice(element, 1);
}
```

Or go through this example:

HTML code

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="product in products" ng-click='slice($index);'>
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{product.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code

```
$scope.products = [
                    {id:'1', name:'IPhone6', price: '1,000 AED', quantity: '2'},
                    {id:'2', name:'Samsung Mini', price: '750 AED', quantity: '1'},
                    {id:'3', name:'Dell Laptop', price: '1700 AED', quantity: '3'},
                    {id:'4', name:'HCL Monitor 7"', price: '650 AED', quantity: '7'},
                  ];

$scope.slice = function(element){
     $scope.friends.splice(element, 1);
}
```